# loading custom.js file after jquery is loaded

Tags: theme-development, functions

I am adding a javascript file through the functions.php file. I am using the method as suggested on [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script). One question I have is that what is the best way to handle the version number column. Is it recommended to send the version of jquery or the version of the script I am loading?
Using this code.

```
<?php
function my_scripts_method() {
// register your script location, dependencies and version
   wp_register_script('custom_script',
   get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom_script.js',
   array('jquery'),
   '1.0' );
 // enqueue the script
  wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
  }
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version is the version of your own script, and is appended to the filename in the src attribute of the script tag. This is so you can employ long-term caching on the client-side and still insure a new version of your script will be fetched from the server rather than local cache if you update it.

Comment: Just what I neded